# Omission of Auxiliaries

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I have heard this sentence, said by somebody:

1. Okay, let's check your homework. Sentence 1... correct, sentence 2... also correct, sentence 3 correct as well, and sentence 4... correct, too.

Now,  I've really wondered why there's no *is* used. I suspect there's a pattern saying when we can omit the auxiliaries in such cases, so is there? I have searched about omission of auxiliaries in some ďictionaries, but, unfortunately, I was unable to find anything about such a sophisticated question as this one, posted by me personally.

Comment: If you're reading data from a table or form, you just read what is written in each column or cell. AFAIK this is done in most or every language, not just English. It's not really grammar, just lists.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about how people read out listed items in tables (actual or notional), which has nothing to do with normal syntax or other aspects of "Use of English"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even sophisticated speakers can use informal language when marking a test. Yes? Sure.

Answer (score 1):

You must be careful when you consider the use of the forms derived from "to be". You are really dealing with two very different verbs, one a full verb, which therefore has meaning, and an auxiliary, which has very little meaning. In your sentence "to be" is not the auxiliary, it has meaning.

There is really not much to wonder about; it's a matter of common sense. You are facing a repetitive task and the important word in this repetition is correct, so that is all you keep. You might even have chosen to do away with the word "sentence" after the first sentence. Of course, this is all informal.

The pattern of omission or of ellipsis, as it is more often called, is "< be + adjective>", but it does not tell you anything: it is merely valid or it is not, or, possibly, it is valid sometimes only. In the context of your sentence, it is valid.